# Studies Outside Quebec

Tags: immigration, canada, qualifications

I'm a software developer who wants to apply to the Quebec Skilled Worker Program.

I graduated as a Systems Engineering (original name in Spanish "Ingeniería de Sistemas") 1 year ago (5 1/2 years of studies). In my career we learnt about 2 main fields: programming (software) and network infrastructure (Cisco-related stuff). Every student had to learn both, but some acquired more experience in one field than the other.

I chose the software one, so that's why I'm a developer as I mentioned. I'm interested in knowing if Quebec would consider my Systems Engineering degree equivalent to a "Computer Science" or "Computer Engineering" degree or would it count as a "Electrical, Electronic and Communications Engineering" degree based on the [Area of Training table (PDF)](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/publications/en/diverses/list-training.pdf)?

One of the first two would give me 16 points towards the skilled worker program while the third one would give me 12 points.

Would my current knowledge and experience (2+ years working as a developer), influence what area of training my degree would fit into when I apply for the ["Comparative evaluation of studies done ouside Quebec"](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/forms/search-title/comparative-evaluation/)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @adipro Does Quebec count a systems engineering degree as the same as a computer science or computer engineering? These get the most points. It might fit with "Electrical, Electronic and Communications Engineering" which receives less points.

Comment: I don't know Quebec's exact definition of computer science, but generally it would be considered targeted toward software development, so I would think it would match more closely to OP's actual Systems Engineering degree result than electrical, electronic or communications engineering.